# Debug Websockets App with Intellij in Ruby Project using Puma and Bundler

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, websocket, bundler, puma

I am following the Heroku guide for websockets in Ruby https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets. For this I have to execute *bundle exec puma -p $Port* from the Terminal and my app runs just fine.

The thing is I want to debug my app from Intellij and I have no idea how to set up my run configuration in this IDE. My project is not a Rails project and it closely resembles the Heroku example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Run Configuration of type "Rack" and set the Rack config file to your config.ru file.